# My permissions are messed up

Tags: 11.04, permissions, gnome

I recently just installed the gnome3 D.E. on ubuntu 11.04 after and once i did all my permissions got messed up. It won't let me open dropbox and says it's because of a permissions error. Also when i try to change the theme folder in gnome-shell it won't let me because of the same reason.

Comment: Dropbox normally resides in /home. Can you do: `ls -l ~` and post up the results?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe your user files are now owned by root. Try figuring out the user with the `ls -l` command in your home directory.

In case it looks like

```
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root  4096 2011-04-24 14:55 bin
```

instead of

```
drwxr-xr-x  2 queueoverflow queueoverflow  4096 2011-04-24 14:55 bin
```

you can try to claim ownership of all the files by doing `sudo chown -R YOURUSERNAME ~` to set the owner of all files back to your user account. Then you should be able to work again.

For a complete fix, you would then have to do `sudo chgrp -R YOURUSERNAME ~` as well to get everything back into your group as well.

Comment: To do it in one command:

    `sudo chown -R $(id -u):$(id -g)  $HOME`